# .indexOf is not a function - Sum the total amount of a shopping cart

Tags: javascript

I am building a shopping cart and I am having issue getting the total amount of it.

```
let calculPrice = [];
    for (productLocalStorage of productLocalStorage) {
    let article = productLocalStorage.prix;
    calculPrice.push(article);
    };
    
    const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
    const totalPrice = calculPrice.reduce(reducer, 0);

    console.log(totalPrice);
```

To get the total amount I've created a loop which work fine but I have an error when I try to delete an item

```
"cart.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: productLocalStorage.indexOf is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cart.js:77)"
```

This is my event from my delete button

```
let reachDeleteButton = document.querySelectorAll(".product-delete");
      console.log(reachDeleteButton);
        //Creation d'un tableau vide
      let tab = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < reachDeleteButton.length; i++){
          reachDeleteButton[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
                //Récupération de l'index du produit associé au bouton supprimer
                
                let getIndexOnLocalStorage = productLocalStorage.indexOf(productLocalStorage[i]);
                    console.log(getIndexOnLocalStorage);
                    tab = productLocalStorage
                let response = confirm("Vous allez retirer ce produit de votre panier, voulez-vous continuer?")

                if (response == true ) {
                    tab.splice(getIndexOnLocalStorage, 1)
                    productLocalStorage = localStorage.setItem("product", JSON.stringify(tab));
                    window.location.href ="cart.html";}

                else {
                }

          })
              }
```

Comment: is `for (productLocalStorage of productLocalStorage)` a typo? Your object keys are the same variable name as the object itself, so it'll overwrite the original object.

Comment: The error essentially means that at the time you're calling `.indexOf()` on it, `productLocalStorage` is not an array. You need to do basic debugging as in `console.log(productLocalStorage);` and find out where you went wrong.

Comment: Be careful that when your `for` loop has ended, `i` is equal to `reachDeleteButton.length` and `productLocalStorage[i]` is therefore always equal to `productLocalStorage[reachDeleteButton.length]`. I suggest you replace your `for` loop by a `foreach`.

Comment: Another problem is that you mix together things which should be separate. This a general advice: ask yourself "does this piece of code need to know about this other thing?". If it doesn't need to know, be generic, partition things. For example, when you make a total: `productLocalStorage.prix` does the surrounding code need to know  that the product comes from localStorage? No, it doesn't.

Comment: Last thing: learn about other Array methods. `reduce` is usually harder to learn than the other ones, you will really enjoy learning about them. In this instance your code would have benefited from `map`: `totalPrice = productLocalStorage.map(product => product.prix).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`. That's a lot more readable (if you ignore the fact that `productLocalStorage` would be better named `products` with an "s" because it's a collection)